# duplicate symbols for architecture armv7(FMDB)

Tags: ios, linker-errors, cocoapods, duplicate-symbol

There are a lot of question about duplicate symbols for architecure XXX, but I didn't got answer of my question.
In my scenario,I use Cocoapod,and import FMDB,But when I integrate another third party SDK,And when I build the project,and got the error as below: 
[image]

Is there any solution can fix my linker error?
PS: I'm not familiar with cocoapod,and here is my pod file

```js
platform :ios, "7.0"

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

target "Catalyst", :exclusive => true do
pod 'FMDB'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
# ...ignore other pod lib.
end
```

Comment: What is the other third party SDK you are integrating? The most likely scenario is that it is dependent on FMBD and therefore you're importing it twice.

Comment: the third party SDK is a framework, that I don't have source code and FMDB don't have a .h file as well. It was used inside of SDK. And you can see the pic that the SDK is MaaS360SDK.framework.

Comment: Does MaaS360SDK utilise FMDB then? It appears to based on your screenshot.

Comment: yup, from the linker error, I think MaaS SDK had used FMDB. And my code also use FMDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot it looks like MaaS360SDK depends on FMDB and therefore includes it in it's package. By importing it through Cocoapods you are importing a second copy, hence the duplicate symbols. Remove the pod and you should be able to access FMDb through the MaaS360SDK.

Comment: yes, you're right. I had tried to remove FMDB from pod, but MaaS360SDK didn't leave .h file (like this:#import "FMDatabase.h"
)to use FMDB.

Comment: If you import MassS360SDK you should probably be able to access FMDB still.

Comment: yes,you're right, I find the similar header file and also can access FMDB, Thank you